# Mixing function templates and ordinary functions

Tags: c++, templates

I have a couple of small helper functions declared in a header file. It looks like this:

```
//contents of foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void foo1(int a);
template <class mType>
void foo2( mType b);

#endif

//contents of foo.cpp
#include foo.h

void foo1(int a)
{
  ...
}

template <class mType>
void foo2( mType a)
{
  ...
}
```

Normally when having only function templates i would add an `#include "foo.cpp"`
at the end of foo.h to make the implementation of the template functions visible to the compiler at compile time. However when mixing function templates and ordinary functions this approach doesn't seem to work. How would one resolve having template functions and ordinary functions in such a case?

Answer (score 2):

You should never include a cpp file.

Put the implementation of the template in a header file. If you want to keep it separate then make 2 header files.

```
//contents of foo.h

void foo1(int a);

template <class mType>
void foo2( mType a)
{
...
}

//contents of foo.cpp
#include foo.h

void foo1(int a)
{
...
}
```

(Alternatively, there is the `export` keyword, although no major compilers support it and it has been removed in C++11 In other words, don't use it)

Comment: I am half tempted to downvote for even mentioning the useless never implemented by anyone `export` keyword. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: @AlexandreC. I figured using `export` is better than including a cpp file.

Comment: @Pubby8 Thanks for the answer. I was hoping there was a more elegant solution to this. I'm wondering about your statement to never include a cpp file at the end of a header file. It is mentioned to be a possible method to structure template code. See for example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/templatesourceorg.aspx

Comment: @tisch Someone else can probably answer it better to why cpp files should not be included. From what I know, cpp files are the ones that get compiled - including them causes duplicate code spread across different translation units.